# Parallel Writes to NFS-backed File

Tags: chapel

UPDATE: I had each node write to a separate file, and when the separate files were concatenated together the result was correct. I also updated the code to attempt a channel flush and file sync after each write of a single record, but there are still issues between nodes 0 and 1, now. If I make Node 0 sleep for a few seconds before it starts its iteration of the `coforall` loop, the records come out correct. If not, the last few hundred bytes of Node 0's records seem to be reliably overwritten with NULL bytes, up to the start of Node 1's records. The issues between Node 1 and Node 2, and Node 2 and Node 3, seem to not show up anymore.

Additionally, if I suppress either Node 0 or Node 1 from writing, I see the fully-formed records from the un-suppressed node written correctly to the file. In the case that Node 1 is suppressed, I see 9,997 100B records (or 999,700) correct bytes followed by NULL bytes in the file where Node 1's suppressed records would go. In the case that Node 0 is suppressed, I see exactly 999,700 NULL bytes in the file, after which Node 1's records begin.

---

Original Post:

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with parallel writes from different nodes to a shared NFS-backed file on disk. At the moment, I suspect that something is wrong with the way writes to the disk happen on the NFS server.

I'm working on adapting MPI+C code that uses `pwrite` to write to coordinated chunks of a file. If I try to have the equivalent locales in Chapel write to the file inside of a `coforall` loop, I end up with the bits of the file around the node boundaries messed up - usually the final few hundred bytes of each node's data are garbled. However, if I have just one locale iterate through the data on all locales and write it, the data comes out correctly. That is, I use the same data structures to calculate the offsets, but only Locale 0 seeks to that offset and performs the writes.

I've verified that the offsets into the file that each locale runs do not overlap, and I'm using a single channel per task, defined from within the `on loc do` block, so that tasks don't share a single channel.

Are there known issues with writing to a file from different locales? A lot of the documentation makes it seem like this is known to be safe, but an unsubstantiated guess seems to indicate that there are issues with caching of file contents; when examining the incorrect data, the bits that are incorrect seem to be the original data from the file in that location at the beginning of the program.

I've included the relevant routine below, in case you easily spot something I missed. To make this serial, I convert the `coforall loc in Locales` and `on loc do` block into a `for j in 0..numLocales-1` loop, and replace `here.id` with `j`. Please let me know what else would help get to the bottom of this. Thanks!

```
proc write_share_of_data(data_filename: string, ref record_blocks) throws {

    coforall loc in Locales {
        on loc do {

            var data_file: file = open(data_filename, iomode.cwr);
            var data_writer = data_file.writer(kind=ionative, locking=false);
            var line: [1..100] uint(8);

            const indices = record_blocks[here.id].D;

            var local_record_offset = + reduce record_blocks[0..here.id-1].D.size;

            writeln("Loc ", here.id, ": record offset is ", local_record_offset);

            var local_bytes_offset = terarec.terarec_width_disk * local_record_offset;

            data_writer.seek(start=local_bytes_offset);

            for i in indices {
                var write_rec: terarec_t = record_blocks[here.id].records[i];
                line[1..10] = write_rec.key;
                line[11..98] = write_rec.value;
                line[99] = 13;  // \r
                line[100] = 10;  // \n
                data_writer.write(line);
                lines_written += 1;
            }

            data_file.fsync();
            data_writer.close();
            data_file.close();
        }
    }

    return;

}
```

Comment: On an old Solaris computer, we used to set `actimeo=0` for shares that are accessed frequently (mail folders) it might be worthwhile looking at the mount or share options on your NFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an answer here that solved my particular problem, though it doesn't explain the behavior seen. I ended up changing the outer loop from `coforall loc in Locales` to `for loc in Locales`. This isn't too big of an issue since it's all writing to one file anyway - I doubt that multiple locales can actually make much headway in all attempting to write concurrently to a single file on an NFS server. As a result, the change still allows nodes to write the data they have locally to NFS, rather than forcing Node 0 to collect and then write the data on behalf of all locales. This amounts to only adding idle time to the write operation commensurate with the time it takes Locale 0 to start the remote task on other nodes when the previous node has finished writing, which for the application at hand is not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried specifying start/end in [file.writer](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.file.writer) instead of using `seek`? Does that change anything? What about specifying the end offset for the [channel.seek](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.channel.seek) call? Does it matter if the file is created and has the appropriate size before you start?

Other than that, I wonder if this issue would appear for both NFS and Lustre. If it appears for both it might well be a Chapel bug. It sounds from your description that the C program was using this pattern, which points to it being a bug. But, have you run C code doing this on your setup? If it being a Chapel bug seems most likely after further investigation, we would appreciate a [bug report issue](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues) with a reproducer.

I know that NFS does not always do what one would like, in terms of data consistency. It's my understanding that it has "close to open" semantics but it's unclear to me what that means in the context of opening a file and writing to a particular region within it, in parallel from different locales.

From [Why NFS Sucks by Olaf Kirch](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2006/ols2006v2-pages-59-72.pdf):

> An NFS client is permitted to cache changes locally and send them to
> the server whenever it sees fit. This sort of lazy write-back greatly
> helps write performance, but the flip side is that everyone else will
> be blissfully unaware of these change before they hit the server. To
> make things just a little harder, there is also no requirement for a
> client to transmit its cached write in any particular fashion, so
> dirty pages can (and often will be) written out in random order.

I read two implications from this paragraph that are relevant to your situation here:

1. The writes you do on different locales can be observed by the NFS server in an arbitrary order. (However as I understand it, the data should be sent to the server by the time your `fsync` call returns).
2. These writes are done at an OS page granularity (usually 4k). (Note that this is more a hypothesis I am making than it is a fact. It should be tested or further investigated).

It would be interesting to check if 2. is a plausible explanation for the behavior you are seeing. For example, you could explore having each locale operate on a multiple of 4096 records (or potentially try writing records of 4096 bytes each) and see if that changes the behavior. If 2 is indeed the explanation, it should be possible to create a C program that demonstrates the behavior as well.